# Referencing a variable before "state" assignment in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that starts out like this:

```
function DetailedView({ country }) {
      useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${country.capital[0]}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}`
          )
          .then((response) => setWeather(response.data));
      }, [country]);
    
      const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
```

As you can see, there's a piece of state called `weather` and I need to make a query based on my `country` prop to receive a capital city and then set the `weather` based on that city inside of my `useEffect` hook.

Later on in my code I end up referencing the `weather` variable. However, initially it's undefined, so I get an error if I try to use the dot operator on it to retrieve a property from the object. To combat this, I end up having to check if the object is empty before accessing a property from it:

```
 {Object.keys(weather).length !== 0 ? (
    <>
      <p>Temperature: {weather.main.temp - 273}</p>
      <img
        src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
        alt="icon"
      ></img>
      <p>Wind Speed: {weather.wind.speed} m/s</p>
    </>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
```

This approach works, but it seems like I might be doing something that's not idiomatic in React. Is there a best practice for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data

Comment: Instead of an empty object initially, people usually set it to `null`. Then check for weather, and if you want to return nothing in React, please don't return an empty string, instead, return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is on the right direction. I see code like this very often.

You might want to return `null` instead of an empty string:

```
...
) : 
  null
}
```

Some people prefer to use the shorter statement for conditional render:

```
{(Object.keys(weather).length !== 0) && (
    <>
      <p>Temperature: {weather.main.temp - 273}</p>
      <img
        src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`}
        alt="icon"
      ></img>
      <p>Wind Speed: {weather.wind.speed} m/s</p>
    </>)
}
```